# How to return the remaining a line in a file after a specific string

Tags: python-3.x, string, txt

I have files that contain both strings and floats. I am interested in finding the floats after a specific string. Any help in writing such a function that reads the file look for that specific string and returns the float after it will be much appreciated.

Thanks

An example of a file is

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa  bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb  cccccccccc
qq vvv rrr ssssa 22.6
zzzzx bbbb 12.0
xxxxxxxxxx -1.099
zzzz bbb nnn 33.5
```

In this specific example I am interested in getting the float after the string 'xxxxxxxxxx' and ignore the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read the entire file into a string and then use `re.findall`:

```py
str_to_search = 'xxxxxxxxxx'

with open('input.txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.read()
    num = re.findall(r'^' + str_to_search + r' (-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)', lines, flags=re.M)
    print(num)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Tim, for the answer. What about if the string I am using to find the string is a variable? So, I want to have it as a function where the string is the argument since I need to find the float after xxxxxxxxxx and later in my code, I need to find the float after 'zzzz bbb nnn'

Comment: I have edited my answer which now is hopefully more along the lines of what you have in mind.

Comment: Thanks, Tim; I was trying to play with it. I get an empty list. It is probably a fault on my side, but I am still unable to figure it out.

Comment: Here is a link to a working demo: https://rextester.com/WOXZ97737 ... your data could be the issue, or perhaps you are not using the code in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, could it be the string I am using contains integers?

Comment: Oh...your question stated you expected _floats_, not integers.  Check the updated answer which covers integers as well.

Comment: I am not if it is relevant, but the actual file I am scanning has around 400k lines.

Comment: I expect floats, but the string I use to fetch the line has integers. So, I tested it using the old code, and it did work for the demo example, but not for actual data file

Comment: Hello Tim, I just copied part of the data; please see it below. You will get an empty list if you run it with the data below.

Comment: Tim, after testing it thoroughly, it seems that the issue is with negative floats.

Comment: OK...I have updated to allow for negative floats.